# ANT_HOME not working on .bat file

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to set a DocuShare language pack, and up to now, everything worked just fine: done the translating, executed setJar.bat, but when I try to build the .jar file for my language pack with buildJar.bat, it says that ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME. 
I can clearly detect on a separate cmd window both ant and java are present. JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME and Path variables have been set, both Java and ant work, but just not with the translation .bat files.
The echo on both ant and Java home variables is the following:

```
%ANT_HOME% =  C:\Xerox\DS5L10N\DSJar\apache-ant-1.7.0
%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```

Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: change these %ANT_HOME% =  C:\Xerox\DS5L10N\DSJar\apache-ant-1.7.0
%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21 to %ANT_HOME=%C:\Xerox\DS5L10N\DSJar\apache-ant-1.7.0
%JAVA_HOME%=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: You are basically telling me the same thing, the paths are just the ones above. The % are just for the variables that I echo on command prompt, and the path on the right is the one that appears.

Comment: could you please check the spaces before and after = sign ?

Comment: If I run ant -version, this is what I get: 
Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on December 13 2006

Comment: The spaces above are just so the paths align, so you can see more clearly... 
echo %ANT_HOME% results with the path above

Comment: Please run the following command in a cmd window: "set ANT_HOME". Paste the exact results as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Delete ANT_HOME, the message is ACTUALLY saying it needs to use a project specific path. You are overriding it by setting ANT_HOME.